# Finding $f(B)$, $f^{-1}(C)$ and $f(D)$ when $f: \mathcal P(\mathbb Z)\to \mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$, $f(X)=X'$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Consider $f: \mathcal P(\mathbb Z)\to \mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$ defined as $f(X)=X'$, where $\mathbb Z$ is the universal set. Find $f(B)$, $f^{-1}(C)$ and the inverse image of element $D$, when $B=\left\{ \{3k \colon k\in \mathbb N\} , \emptyset \right\}$, $C=\left\{ \{z\in\mathbb{Z} \colon 2| z\}, \mathbb N \right \}$ and $D$ is the set of all prime numbers.

**My attempt:**

$$f(B)=B'$$ Using complement definition $$B'= \mathbb Z \setminus B$$

The set $\{3k \colon k\in \mathbb N\}$ contains positive multiples of $3$, i.e $\{3,6,9,12,\dots\}$. Therefore its complement should be $\{3k+1:k\in \mathbb Z\} \cup \{3k+2:k\in \mathbb Z\}\cup \{0\}$, i.e zero, and all other integers that are not divisible by $3$.

The complement of the empty set is the universal set: $$\emptyset'=\mathbb Z$$

Thus $$f(B)=B'=\mathbb Z \setminus B =\{\{3k+1:k\in \mathbb Z\} \cup \{3k+2:k\in \mathbb Z\}\cup \{0\}, \mathbb Z\}$$

---

$f^{-1}(C)=C'$, because $f(C')=C$

The set $\{z\in\mathbb{Z} \colon 2| z\}$ contains all integers divisible by $2$. Its complement should be $\{z \in \mathbb Z:2z+1\}$
Complement of $\mathbb N$ should be $\mathbb Z^{-}\cup\{0\}$ (assuming $0$ is not a natural number)

Thus
$$f^{-1}(C)=\{\{z \in \mathbb Z : 2z+1\}, \{\mathbb Z^{-}\cup\{0\}\}\}$$

---

Inverse image of element $D$

$f^{-1}(D)=D'$, because $f(D')=D$
$D'=\mathbb Z \setminus D$ (the set of composite numbers and non-positive integers)

$$f^{-1}(D)=\{\mathbb Z \setminus \mathbb P\}$$

---

Did I approach this correctly? Any help or tips are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do, I will assume that $\mathbb{N}$ does not contain $0$, and define $\mathbb{Z}^- := \{n \in \mathbb{Z} : n < 0\}$.

---

First, by definition
\begin{align*}
f(B)
&= \{f(\{3 k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}), f(\emptyset)\}\\
&= \{\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{3 k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}, \mathbb{Z} \setminus \emptyset\}\\
&= \{\{0\} \cup \mathbb{Z}^- \cup \{3 k - 2 : k \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{3 k - 1 : k \in \mathbb{N}\}, \mathbb{Z}\}.
\end{align*}
This is a bit different to what you have written (you are missing the negative multiples of $3$).

---

Next, the statement $f^{-1}(C) = C'$ is not correct. For starters, $f^{-1}(C)$ should be a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})$ and not merely $\mathbb{Z}$. By the definition of the preimage we instead have
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(C) &= \{S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) : f(S) \in C\}\\
&= \{S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) : \mathbb{Z} \setminus S \in C\}\\
&= \{S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) : \mathbb{Z} \setminus S = \{n : n \in \mathbb{Z}, 2 \mid n\}\}
\cup \{S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) : \mathbb{Z} \setminus S = \mathbb{N}\}\\
&= \{S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) : S = \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{n : n \in \mathbb{Z}, 2 \mid n\}\}
\cup \{S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) : S =  \mathbb{Z} \setminus \mathbb{N}\}\\
&= \{S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) : S = \{n : n \in \mathbb{Z}, 2 \not\mid n\}\}
\cup \{S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) : S = \{0\} \cup \mathbb{Z}^-\}\\
&= \{ \{2 n + 1 : n \in \mathbb{Z}\},
\{0\} \cup \mathbb{Z}^- \}.
\end{align*}
Nonetheless, your calculation has come out right.

---

Finally similarly we can compute that
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(\{D\}) &= \{S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) : \mathbb{Z} \setminus S = D\}\\
&= \{S \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}) : S = \mathbb{Z} \setminus D\}\\
&= \mathbb{Z} \setminus D\\
&= \{n : n \in \mathbb{Z}, \text{ $n$ is not prime}\}.
\end{align*}
This agrees with your calculation (in this case the slight modification $f^{-1}(\{D\}) = D'$ is true, unlike the previous case). I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correcect but for $f^{-1}(D)$ this must be a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ and not a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$. So, it is
$$f^{-1}(D)=D^c=\mathbb{Z}-D=\{k:k\in\mathbb{Z}, k not prime\}$$.
Also for the image of B, $f(B)$ you forgot to take the negative integers.
Finally, the preimage of C is also a set whose elements are subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$. So
$$f^{-1}(C)=\{\{2k+1:k\in\mathbb{Z}\},\mathbb{Z}\cup\ \{0\}\}$$.